# Application-defined or Object-defined Error - Resize Ubound, Application.Transpose

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, runtime-error

I am having an issue with a small code we made for a specific task. In short, the task is to take an input of two columns; (A) containing rows with productsnumbers (and duplicates) and (B) containing a corresponding value for that particular productnumber.

Instead of having 100.000 of rows, we want to have one UNIQUE productnumber in column A and the corresponding (concatenated) values in Column B. This was achieved.

I found most of the code here on stack and changed it a bit. Would love to link, but can't remember where exactly I got it - sorry!
Now, we have  a lot of rows and hence the original code ran into an issue, because the loop variable (i) was dimmed as an Integer.

- TO FIX THAT i quickly changed it to type Long. However, this presents me with another issue: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Debugging tells me it is the commented part below, that presents an issue, but I am unable to fix it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!!

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub groupConcat()
Dim dc As Object
Dim inputArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
```

Getting lastRow

```
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Formatting E to text

```
Range("E1:E20000").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Clear worksheet before any further work is done

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:E20000").ClearContents
Set dc = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
inputArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Value)

   '-- assuming you only have two columns - otherwise you need two loops
   For i = LBound(inputArray, 2) To UBound(inputArray, 2)
        If Not dc.Exists(inputArray(1, i)) Then
            dc.Add inputArray(1, i), inputArray(2, i)
        Else
            dc.Item(inputArray(1, i)) = dc.Item(inputArray(1, i)) _
            & "," & inputArray(2, i)
        End If
   Next i

'--output into sheet
Sheets(1).Range("D2").Resize(UBound(dc.keys) + 1) = _
          Application.Transpose(dc.keys)
```

ISSUE BELOW

> ```
> Sheets(1).Range("E2").Resize(UBound(dc.items) + 1) = _
>           Application.Transpose(dc.items)
> ```

```
Set dc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect you have some long text stored in the items. In some versions of Excel `Transpose` won't cope with that so you'd be better off writing your own transpose function. I'm also not really sure why you transpose the initial inputarray - seems like a waste of time to me.

Comment: Hello.

Thank you. I believe to are correct. I tried the below and end up getting the same error. Some of the items do have a lot of text in them. This might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the double transpose. Try this version and see if it works for you:

```
    Sub DictMatch()
        Dim arr, j As Long, dict As Object
        arr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2 'load source
        Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create dictionary lateB
        With dict 'used because I'm to lazy to retype dict everywhere :)
            
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr) 'traverse source
                If Not .Exists(arr(j, 1)) Then 'set key if I don't have it yet in dict
                    .Add Key:=arr(j, 1), Item:=arr(j, 2)
                Else
                    dict(arr(j, 1)) = dict(arr(j, 1)) & "," & arr(j, 2)
                End If
                Debug.Print arr(j, 1), dict(arr(j, 1))
            Next j
        End With
        
        With Sheet1 'dump target array to sheet
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
            .Cells(1, 2).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! First of all, thank you so much for giving this a try.

Unfortunately, I still end up with Run-time error '1004' :-(

Comment: Can you post some sample data. If i can reproduce the error I'll have a look.